# Web.config redirect to another URL without trailing slash

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7, web-config, windows-server-2008

Very strange thing; I'm using the following in web.config file to redirect everything from one domain to specific page on another domain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.example.com/my-page.html" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

However, trailing slash is appended to the URL, resulting in a 404:

```
http://www.example.com/my-page.html/
```

How can I force redirect WITHOUT the trailing slash?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `exactDestination="true"` to your config. It should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.example.com/my-page.html" exactDestination="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```